# How to mute notifications of a telegram user with telethon?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I was trying how to **mute a telegram user with telethon.**

I tried searching in the official documentation of telethon.
I also tried searching in google I found nothing.

Please help me. **How to mute a telegram user with telethon.**

Comment: You can't mute a user. You can block a user or disable the notification for a chat with the user. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: From the title, I'm guessing you want to disable notifications. This is how to do that: https://core.telegram.org/method/account.updateNotifySettings

Comment: Thank you @Dschoni you  answered what I wanted. Thank you very much.